# How to add additional Coordinate systems to ArcGIS Server WFS service?

Tags: arcgis-server, wfs

Has anyone added additional coordinate systems to an external WFS GetCapabilities file? I need to support webmercator to a wfs service but cannot find any documentation on how to do it. Has anyone an idea of how to do this?

Comment: What version of WFS is it?   The WFS 1.0 specification only allows for one advertised CRS for example.

Comment: I am using both versions 1.0.0 and 1.1.0. I have seen in the specification that the parameter <wfs:OtherSRS> is used. However, when I simply add my SRS ArcGIS Online displays the point someone in the arabian golf and not central europe.

Comment: `<OtherWFS>` is correct for WFS 1.1.0 are you using full urns like: `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857`

Comment: Yes...I did. I have also just created a new service where the native geometries were reprojected into EPSG:3857 and ArcGIS Online is also not recognising the service.

Comment: did you try with other references like `ESRI:102100 ` and `EPSG:900913` as well?